# QuerySelector() returns null

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a simple blackjack game and I want to add a image to my page using:

```js
let blackjackGame = {
'you': {'scoreSpan': '#your-blackjack-result', 'div':'your-box', 'score':0},
'dealer': {'scoreSpan': '#dealer-blackjack-result', 'div':'dealer-box', 'score':0},
}

const YOU = blackjackGame['you'];

let cardImage = document.createElement('img');
cardImage.src = 'static/images/Q.png';
console.log(cardImage.src);
document.querySelector(YOU['div']).appendChild(cardImage);
```

```html
<div class="flex-blackjack-row-1">
            <div id="your-box">
                <h2>You: <span id="your-blackjack-result">0</span></h2>
            </div>
            <div id="dealer-box">
                <h2>Dealer: <span id="dealer-blackjack-result">0</span></h2>
            </div>
</div>

<div>
                <button class="btn-lg btn btn-primary mr-2" id="blackjack-hit-button">Hit</button>
                <button class="btn-lg btn btn-warning mr-2" id="blackjack-stand-button">Stand</button>
                <button class="btn-lg btn btn-danger mr-2" id="blackjack-deal-button">Deal</button>
            </div>
```

But as you can see, it gives me an error. What must I do?

Comment: There's no element with the tagname of `your-box` in your HTML.

Comment: It's fixed now.

Comment: Nope, still no such __tag__ in the markup.

Comment: In the second line of the HTML code

Comment: How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you add two elements that will be used to display the images ( I chose simple DIV elements with ID attributes for convenience ) you can tweak the `blackjackGame` slightly to include the `img src` and use a single piece of code to populate the images

```js
let blackjackGame = {
  'you': {'scoreSpan':'#your-blackjack-result', 'div':'your-box', src:'https://picsum.photos/120/80?random=1', 'score':0},
  'dealer': {'scoreSpan': '#dealer-blackjack-result', 'div':'dealer-box', src:'https://picsum.photos/120/80?random=2', 'score':0},
};
Object.keys( blackjackGame ).forEach(key=>{
  let expr='div#'+blackjackGame[ key ]['div'];
  let img=document.createElement('img');
    img.src=blackjackGame[ key ]['src'];

  document.querySelector( expr ).appendChild( img );
})
```

```html
<div id='your-box'></div>

<div>
  <button class="btn-lg btn btn-primary mr-2" id="blackjack-hit-button">Hit</button>
  <button class="btn-lg btn btn-warning mr-2" id="blackjack-stand-button">Stand</button>
  <button class="btn-lg btn btn-danger mr-2" id="blackjack-deal-button">Deal</button>
</div>

<div id='dealer-box'></div>
```

Comment: What is that 'keys' of you? Sorry but I'm still a beginner. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `keys` refers to the index within the `object literal` ( `blackjackGame` is, in this case, an `Object Literal` ) and `key` is the individual index. `Object.keys` is an iterator and allows you to iterate through all properties of the object.

Comment: give you code? for what? Have you tried running the snippet above?

Comment: Thank you but I don't want to save it in the blackjackgame object but only later add the image to the page

Comment: ok - it was simply an idea... use the static path you had before

Answer (score -1):

YOU here is just an object and not a node. In order for querySelector to find it, you need to use document.createElement for it, add the corresponding attributes, and add the element to your page. Then you can address it inside of querySelector in the same way you'd address it from a CSS file (e.g. using a tag name, class name, etc.)

Comment: _“YOU here is just an object and not a node.”_ – it doesn’t need to be a node. The purpose of calling `querySelector`, is to _find_ some element, based on some selector. `YOU['div']` _provides_ that selector here, the value is `your-box`. The problem simply is, that that selector makes no sense to begin with.

Comment: Of course, there you go: https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-bouman-e5ejn?file=/src/index.js

Comment: @CBroe true, but the author still has to make an element out of the object first, doesn't he?

Comment: Depends, on whether this configuration is supposed to just provide selectors that find an already _existing_ element, or whether this was supposed to specify that a _new_ element should be created. OP’s question really lacks the necessary context in that regard.

Comment: OK, so now you basically just need to add '#' to your querySelector, so it'll be looking for an element with an id 'your-box' (document.querySelector('#your-box'))
In this case, you can use the backticks: document.querySelector(`#${YOU['div']}`)